Book about supernatural beings running stores in a mall
I am trying to find a book series I can not remember the name of.
It is about a guy who works in a mall the has each store run by a different supernatural being. I think each store is considered an embassy for those kinds of supernatural beings.
As for the main character of the series, he is a supernatural being as well the has the ability to teleport and/or create portals.

"We can remember it for you in retail". Sorry, couldn't resist.

Searching based on various keywords in your post turns up Mr. Hartley (2014), first book in the "Alternate Places" trilogy by "P.S. Power."
Quoting from the blurb on Goodreads:

Zack needs to find work, fast.
That's not a new thing, since jobs are hard to come by in these tough economic times. So, deciding to try something new, he takes a shortcut through a tree, to an interspatial nexus across town. It isn't the sort of thing that most people do, but this time it works out pretty well, and he finds employment. At a secret embassy, masquerading as a rather humble candle shop.
Mr. Hartley isn't just an ordinary store clerk, however, and very soon strange things become apparent to him that few would notice. Like the vampires running the place across the way, or the attractive giantess that keeps watching him more than a little bit too closely.

A review mentions his powers in a bit more detail:

The book focuses on Zack Hartley, a recluse, who has a special power that sets him apart from everyone else, in that he can travel through special gateways that allow him to go from point A to B in a matter of seconds. The story follows Zack as he develops his powers and in doing so causes a ripple effect throughout the supernatural world.

The description and reviews make me very much not wish to read this, so I won't be chasing down a copy to supply quotes.
